# Same css file behaves differently on different hosts

Tags: html, css

I have the exact same css file.

On development server it works fine. On release server some margins and heights are broken.

In inspector tools the applied css is exactly the same on the two hosts for an element (I checked every single property).

- I tried on different browsers
- I cleared my browser cache
- I tried copying dev `<head>` and putting it in release
- I tried removing all links from release head and only applying the file

Nothing of the above works, everything is the same but on release it's broken

This is a thing that worked 100% on dev but not on release

```js
document.querySelectorAll("link[rel=stylesheet]").forEach((elm) => {
  elm.remove()
})
x = document.createElement('link')
x.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet')
x.setAttribute('href', 'https://example.com/myfile.css')
document.head.appendChild(x)
```

Sample broken things

- on dev (correct)
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4S1t.png)
- on release (broken)
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmrjj.png)

Comment: Can you tell us more about your problem pls?

Comment: What do you want to know more ?

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of the things you tried?

Comment: Added a sample code

Comment: Hey riko. Does the `forEach` function on the DOMNodeList object that contains stylesheet link nodes really work? Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Could https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/" help you?

Comment: Everything works, and I added sample pictures

Comment: @johannes No, it didn't help, still broken

Answer (score 0):

The beloved "works-on-my-machine" phenomenon. Who hasn't ever argued that something works locally and, therefore, it works everywhere? :D

There are many possible causes, let's discuss two common ones!

1. Differences on dev/prod environments:

- are the operating systems identical (or e.g. different linux distros)?
- maybe different software installed?

2. leftover configuration on development environment

- Have you changed any settings for previous project that may cause the program to work on your dev machine?

What happens if you set up a new development virtual machine (only installing what you need for the program to run), does the program work there?

Comment: I am sorry to tell you that everything is deployed via pipelines with docker :D

Comment: Ah I see, but there could still be differences between your dev/prod containers right? What do you see in your browser console on prod?